# Do YUM and RPM package manager share the same Package

Tags: package, rpm, yum, package-managers

Do YUM and RPM package manager share the same Package

I mean if AWSCLI is installed by RPM,

Can YUM refer this package? Can YUM remove and update the this package?

Same question for Homebrew/Brew? Does it share package with YUM or RPM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yum (and DNF) is a system utility that is built on top of RPM. Yum calls rpmlib and if you install a package using Yum you can remove it by RPM and vice versa.

I never used Homebrew, but from a quick check, the Homebrew is specifically designed to maintain a separate user-owned directory hierarchy. This is orthogonal to an RPM philosophy, so I guess that if you install something using Homebrew it cannot be handled by an RPM.